# Kiu estas la Esperanta termino por "sanaliitto/ordfogning/Wortverbindung/open compound"?

Tags: word-usage, terminology

Temas verŝajne pri simpla demando, sed mi ne trovis respondon.

Oni uzas terminojn "kunmetita vorto" aŭ "kunmetaĵo" por konstruaĵo de du aŭ pluraj vortoj, kiujn oni skribas kune. Tiuj estas multaj en Esperanto.

Kiel oni nomas konstruaĵon, **tutaĵon** de du aŭ pluraj vortoj, kiujn oni ne skribas kune sed (preskaŭ ĉiam) uzas kune? Mi pensas ekz. pri esprimoj "kunmetita vorto" (kontraŭ "kunmetaĵo") aŭ "la japana lingvo" (kontraŭ "la japana"). En la finna oni nomas tiajn "sanaliitto" (laŭlitere "vorta unuigo"), en la sveda "ordfogning", en la germana "Wortverbindung" kaj mi pensas, ke la angla termino estas "open compound" aŭ "fixed phrase".

Comment: Mi [menciis tiun demandon](https://t.me/c/1116306970/28240) ĉe [telegrama grupo "Esperantologio"](https://esperantologio.telegramo.org/). Eble iu tie scias.

Comment: Mi nun rimarkas ke en la germanlingva Vikipedio la vorto [Wortverbingund](https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wortverbindung) aŭtomate iras al Syntagma el kiu oni poste iras al Sintagmo en la esperanta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ŝajnas, ke mia demando montriĝis malfacila.

Jen estas miaj trovoj:

- **frazeto**: PMEG uzas la terminon por alia afero
- **kolokacio**: neniu trafo en Tekstaro, tro da alilingvaj trafoj per Guglo por "kolokaci"
- **kolokaĵo**: trafoj nek en Tekstaro nek per Guglo; laŭ Vikipedio temas pri alia afero kvankam lingvististo Ilona Koutny ŝajne uzas la terminon en la ĝusta signifo
- **kombino**: PMEG uzas la terminon por alia afero
- **kunstaro**, **kunstaraĵo**: nur malmultaj trafoj en Tekstaro kaj per Guglo por "kunstaro" sed en alia signifo; neniu por "kunstaraĵo"
- **sintagmo**: ŝajnas, ke Ferdinand de Saussure uzis ĉi tiun terminon larĝasence, ankaŭ en la ĝusta signifo, sed nuntempe la signifo estas alia
- **vortgrupo**: nur malmultaj trafoj en Tekstaro, sed en la ĝusta signifo; multaj trafoj per Guglo inter kiuj trafo en ReVo  kaj en la universitata diplomlaboraĵo de Cyril Brosch(!) en la ĝusta signifo
- **vortkombino**, **vortkombinaĵo**: unu trafo en Tekstaro, kie Zamenhof uzas en la signifo de kunmetita vorto; malmultaj aliaj, kiuj havas la ĝustan signifon; la vortaro de Boris Kondratjev uzas la terminon en la ĝusta signifo, sed mi vidas riskon, ke oni miksas ĉi tiujn kun "kombino" de PMEG; malmutaj trafoj per Guglo kaj en alia signifo
- **vortkunligo**, **vortkunligaĵo**: trafoj nek en Tekstaro nek per Guglo (en Esperanto)
- **vortkunmeto**: nur malmultaj trafoj en Tekstaro, sed en alia signifo; multaj per Guglo sed en alia signifo
- **vortkuno**: unu trafo en Tekstaro, eble en la ĝusta signifo; malmultaj per Guglo en la ĝusta signifo
- **vortligo**, **vortligaĵo**: trafoj nek en Tekstaro nek per Guglo

Sume ŝajnas, ke aŭ mi ne povis sufiĉe klare ekspliki, kiun terminon mi serĉas, aŭ ekzistas fuŝo inter Esperantistoj pri terminoj. La lastmenciita estus bedaŭrinda, do mi volas kredi je la unua eblo. Ĉiuokaze la termino ***vortgrupo*** ŝajnas havi la ĝustan signifon. Ĝi havas avantaĝon, ke oni (eĉ profanoj) tuj komprenas ĝin, estas frekventa kaj ne estas miksita kun aliaj. Dankon pro viaj kontribuoj.

Comment: Serĉiloj serĉas ĉefe vortojn, kaj Esperanto uzas kunmetaĵojn. Do, 'vortligo' ne aperigis 'vortliga' por vi. Se vi volas fari tian serĉon vi bezonus serĉi "vortligo" kaj "vortliga" kaj aliajn formojn (ĝis kiam serĉiloj bone regos Esperanton). ´vortlig/o´ ja aperas en pluraj dokumentoj, ekz. [Aktoj de la Akademio](http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/aktoj/aktoj1/vortfarado.html), kiel ´vortliga´. Eble la signifo ne ĝustas, sed la radiko ne ricevas nul trafon (kio ne tiel gravus, _modeloj_ kunmetaj pli gravas). Ĉiuokaze mi pensas ke vi mem jam trovis simplan solvon en antaŭa komento: _vortgrupo_

Comment: Jes, Cyril Brosch mem uzis la terminon **vortgrupo** en sia diplomlaboraĵo. Tiu termino havas multajn avantaĝojn, pri kiuj mi skribis supre.

Answer (score 1):

Mi ne sufiĉe enprofundiĝis en tiun temon por certi, ĉu temas absolute pri la sama nocio, sed laŭ la priskribo almenaŭ tre simila koncepto estas tiu de angla *collocation*, germana *Kollokation*, ankaŭ konata en la [finna](https://fi.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kollokaatio).

La ununura Esperantigo de tiu, kiun mi konas, estas *kolokaĵo*, ne trovebla en PIV, sed ekz. en la lingvistika fakvortareto de [Ilona Koutny](http://www.ais-sanmarino.org/isd/html/isd_ano.html?jaro=1685&numero=5&aldono=AD&kodo=u&lingvo=eo).

Comment: Mi konas la terminon _collocation/Kollokation/kollokaatio_, kolokaĵo, en la kunteksto de datenbazoj, sed tie ĝi havas tute aliajn signifon ol tiu en la lingvistiko (laŭ Vikipedio). Tamen via respondo kondukis min al la vorto [sintagmo](http://vortaro.net/#sintagmo), kiu uzas la terminon "vortgrupo" en sia klarigo.

Comment: "sintagmo" certe ne estas la vorto, kiun vi serĉas, ĉar ĝi nomas sintaksan unuon: _Zamenhof ofte vizitis sian plej junan fizon_ estas frazo el la 3 sintagmoj _Zamenhof_, _ofte vizitis_ kaj _sian plej junan fizon_, sintagmojn oni povas plenigi per unu aŭ pluraj vortoj.
Vi male parolas pri plurvortaj esprimoj leksikaj. Eble kontrolu la artikolon "frazeologio".

Comment: Vi pravas, ke ne estas. Nek estas "kombino", kiun PMEG uzas.

Comment: _ko-_ ne estas prefikso, eĉ ne inter la [neoficialaj](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/neoficialaj_afiksoj/index.html), do vi kreas tute novan radikon _kolok/_ kun evidente ebla verbo _koloki_ nur por eviti _apudmet/_ kaj povi pausi la alilingvan vorton? Tio estus vera preteratento de la jamaj rimedoj lingvaj.

Comment: Mi nenion kreas (se mi kreus, mi dirus _kolokacio_), mi nur nomas la vorton, kiun mi konas kaj kiu estas malgraŭ la kripligo komprenebla al lingvistoj.

Comment: @CyrilRobertBrosch vi pravas, ne estis la plej bona maniero tion diri. Eble, "tiu propono (de Koutny) pezigus la lingvon per nova radiko..." Mi ofte ne komprenas la bezonon nomi simplajn aferojn per novaj apartaj neanalizeblaj (kaj ne tre produktemaj) radikoj, eĉ en mia propra fako. Mia respondo estis iel pelita de tio. Finfine `vortgrupo` estas tre konsiderinda ;)

Comment: @CyrilRobertBrosch, ĉu vi havas ligilon al la lingvistika fakvortareto de Ilona Koutny?

Comment: Ne, ĝi estas ordinara papera libro: https://katalogo.uea.org/index.php?inf=7127
Estas ankaŭ germana-Esperanta-pola versio

Answer (score 1):

Unu difino de *ligi* estas *kunigi plurajn aferojn per ia rilato de sinsekvo, najbareco aŭ kaŭzeco*. Mi do uzus la radikon *lig/*, verŝajne sufikse, kun aldona *kun* se tio helpas substreki la ideon, ekzemple:

```
vortligo
vortkunligo
vortligaĵo
vortkunligaĵo
```

Ekzemplo Zamehofa:

```
...la frazo havas ligantan vorton alian (ekzemple “kiel”)...
```

Nur por montri ke oni povas kunligi sen kunmeti.

```
apudmeto / apudmetaĵo
```

Ankaŭ bonus, kaj ĝi iel akompanas la nocion kunmeto / kunmetaĵo.

Comment: Serĉo per _vortlig_ aŭ _vortkunlig_ rezultigas neniun trafon en Tekstaro.

Comment: Oni ne trovos ĉiun kunmetaĵon en Tekstaro. Ĉefe kiam vi volas esprimi ion fakan aŭ novan, sed ankaŭ pri simplaj aferoj. Ekzemple [galaksiamaso](http://vortaro.net/#galaksiamaso) ne aperos. Lingvo estas homa, do antaŭ ol serĉo en reto (ĉu Tekstaro, Vikipedio, Teksaĵo) venas kompreno. Tiu estas la ideo de Esperanto, ke vi povu diri _malunua_ kaj esti komprenita. Do, se la kunmetaĵon homo bone komprenas, ĝi bonas. La rilato inter kunmetemaj(aglutinaj) lingvoj kaj vortaroj ne samas al tiu de aliaj lingvoj. Se oni ne trovas la kunmetaĵon, oni serĉu _modelon_, ekz. _harligo_(Z), _amligo_(Tekstaro).

Comment: [AKTOJ de la AKADEMIO 1963-1967](http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/aktoj/aktoj1/vortfarado.html) kun alia signifo tamen.

Comment: Kompreneble mi serĉis nur per radikoj. Vi pravas, ke rilatoj ne estas samaj inter lingvoj de malsamaj tipoj, kaj tial ekz. PMEG uzas sian propran terminaron. Fakoj bezonas precizajn terminojn, ne estas bone inventi, se jam antaŭe estas. Mi ne povas kredi, ke mi estus la unua, kiu pripensis pri la afero.

Comment: Tute elpensi estas evitinda, mi samopinias. La bona afero pri [la terminaro de PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/aldonoj/gramatika_vortareto.html) estas ke ĝi rekonas ke, eĉ verkitaj de fakuloj, la plimulto de esperantaj verkoj estos legitaj de nefakuloj. Do, ĉu oni konstruu terminaron por aliaj fakuloj `spondilolistezio` (spondylolisthesis) aŭ ĉu por aliaj esperantistoj `vertebra misŝovo`? Ĉu `kolokacio` aŭ `vortgrupo`? ĉu `lingva adapto` aŭ `lokalizio`? Eble antaŭ ol konstrui terminarojn, ni bezonas kolekti ilin. Ion kiel la [vikia vortaro](https://vivo.kono.be) ekz., laŭ fakoj.